# Backbone.js + Spring MVC. Save model

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, model

When I send a request from JSP FORM, the server side automatically parses data to my ModelObject. But when I send requests from Backbone save() my ModelObject is empty on Server Side. How can I do it like as JSP FORMs?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/member/ajax*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void onSubmitAjax(Member member, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        //member is empty           
        memberManager.saveMember(member); 

    }
```

when I use GET it's working on Client Side:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/member/ajax*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Member showForm(@RequestParam(required = false) Long id, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        Member member = memberManager.getMember(id);
        return member;
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I wrote a [Spring MVC 3.1 backend](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-backbone-todo/) for Backbone.JS Todo sample application. The code of the [CRUD Controller](https://github.com/sdeleuze/spring-backbone-todo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/resthub/todo/TodoController.java) may help you.

Based on your code sample, I think you should check that you have Jackson in your project dependencies, and use the following annotations for your onSubmitAjax method:

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json") @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) @ResponseBody

You should also try [RESThub](http://resthub.github.io/), a nice Spring + Backbone.js stack provided with documentation, tutorial and code samples (Disclaimer: I am RESThub lead developer).

Comment: Thanks for the RESTHub link. Looks impressive and this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I am new too to Backbone.js, but give a look at http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync-emulateJSON.

Comment: Link in answer is dead (*404 File not found*)